# sd card folder is not being created in DDMS

Tags: video, sd-card, ddms

I am new to android.

I intend to make video player which can play video from file as well as web URL. But the problem is that when my emulator runs , a sd card folder should be created in "File Explorer" tab of DDMS perspective in eclipse , which is not happening . That's why I am unable to push any file in the sd card and hence video is not being played.

I have used following code :- check it out the link
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/

Please help me out.

Abhijeet

Answer (score 1):

I think your slashes are backwards.  \sdcard\yourfileonthephone.txt should be /sdcard/yourfileonthephone.txt.  Otherwise, you a "file system is read-only" error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a look at your code, but you can try to use the command line adb tool which you can find in the SDK. That's what I need to do (and works because I created a device with an sd card but it doesn't show up in the DDMS view..
To check if your device has a sd card, use a shell and go to the tools folder in your android installation, make sure you only have one emulator running. Type `adb shell` and check contents with the `ls` command, if there's a folder sdcard then you can use other commands to push and pull files.  If there's no such folder try to create a new device, perhaps that was the problem.
Leave the shell with`Ctrl + C`, and type `adb pull \sdcard\yourfileonthephone.txt yourfileonthecomputer.txt`, files will be saved in the tools folder. Or use `adb push` to store files.
But anyway perhaps there's a way to make it visible in DDMS, would be great :)

PS: Access via DDMS seems to work with devices running 2.1, but not 2.2...

Comment: thnx sonja ......... it was very kind on your part .
i am able to view my sd card folder . But another problem has cropped up . When I run my android project, emulator do starts , but in the DDMS perspective no devices are shown . I have to "Reset adb" from the "Devices" tab . Then only I am able to see the devices and and my project runs successfully . But some sort of error messages appear in the console :-
DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1

Can you help me with that ?